# Can't screw the bolts back on Intel SSD HDD

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure

I have somewhat idiotic problem which I have never expected to have.

So I accidentally unscrewed bolts on my Intel SSD drive mistakenly thinking they are holding plastic slider which came with laptop.

Funny thing is that after I unscrewed them I can't put them back because they seem longer than needed. And I don't want to put super-pressure on them because of fear of breaking the thread.

Here is the photo of how it looks now:

[image]

How come they were fit before? Is it some kind of protection mechanism so I can't hide the fact I removed cover? Now cover is loose because of it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try slowly screwing _against_ the direction you would screw the bolt in and apply soft pressure. After you feel the bolt snapping into its thread (is that the right word?) screw to the other direction. Apply no force though.

Comment: Probably cross threaded already so the reverse method will have 2 snap positions and it will be hard to tell which is the correct one since the correct one will be hard to screw in due to the cross threading, an ugly situation that is hard to correct on small fine threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had been in a similar situation a few days back. You can safely apply "some" pressure on the screws. As the screws are quite afar from anything sensitive on the SSD's PCB. The image below is from an X-25M you can check for open images for your specific SSD to confirm the same.

[image: Intel X-25M]